# Show that a subset $E$ $\subset \Bbb Q$ is not compact in $(\Bbb Q, d)$ and decide whether it is open or not

Tags: compactness, rational-numbers

> Assume $(\Bbb Q, d),$ $d(p, q):= |p -q|$
> is a metric space and
>
> $E := \{p \in \Bbb Q : 2 < p^2 < 3\} = \{p \in \Bbb Q : \sqrt2 < p < \sqrt3\} \subset \Bbb Q.$
>
> I have to show that $E$ is not compact, and furthermore, I have to decide whether E is open or not.
>
> Note: I already proved that $E$ is closed and bounded since this was also part of the task.

**Approach**

Assume $E$ is compact. Then, for every open cover $(U_{i_k})_{i_k \in I}$, there must be a finite number of indices $i_1, ..., i_n \in I$ such that

$$A \subset U_{i_1} \cup ... \cup U_{i_n}.$$

We can assume that $U_{i_k} \subset E.$

Since $\sqrt2 \notin E$, there is no $p \in E$ such that

$$p = \sqrt2.$$

Therefore, and since $E \subset \Bbb Q$ must be countable infinite, we would always find an $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that

$|p - \sqrt2| \le \epsilon$ $\forall p \in E.$ (which already proves that $E$ is open when we show the same thing for $\sqrt3$, but this is obvious)

Since p "converges" to $\sqrt2$ (there might be a better way to express this?), it follows directly that the number of covers can not be finite such that $E$ can not be compact.

Comment: Why can you assume $U_{i_k}\subset E$? (I doubt that.) And that line $A\subset \cdots$ should probably be $E\subset\cup_{k=1,...,n}U_{i_k}$

Comment: consider a special open cover and show that it doesnt have a finite subcover. (take countably infinite disjoint open intervals approximating your set such that neighboring intervals have exactly one irrational between each other)

Comment: I guess you're right. Nontheless, this argument should work the same way when we assume that $U_{i_k} \subset \Bbb Q$ instead. (refering to the first comment)

Comment: Well, if I think about it, it wouldn't work the exact same way, but it would at least be similar.

Comment: the contability is not a proof for existence of such an epsilon (if you cut out a small subinterval of the set around $\sqrt{2}$ the result is still countable and clearly there is no such epsilon)

Comment: and i think what you meant is that for all epsilon there exists such a p^^ what I meant above is that this does not hold by countability. (find other reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show non-compactness, we shall just formalise your convergence idea. 
 
Let $a_n$ be a strictly decreasing sequence tending to $\sqrt{2}$ (for example take alternating terms of the truncated continued fraction) and let $b_n$ be a strictly increasing sequence tending to $\sqrt{3}$. 
Consider the sets $U_n=(a_n,b_n)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ (open by the same argument you gave), then $\cup U_n = (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})\cap \mathbb{Q}$ and are increasing. Thus the union of any finite subset of $U_n$'s looks like $U_N$ where N is the maximum index within this subfamily. Now, as $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational, $U_N \neq E$ and so E is not compact.

Comment: I guess that's a nice way to put it when we could indeed assume that $(U_{i_k})_{i_k} \subset E$, but as it was mentioned in the comments, we are not able to assume so. But this might work out similar if we work outside of $E$.

Comment: To show non-compactness we need only give an open cover with no finite subcover, having $U_n \subset E$ was just an easy example. If you prefer we can define $U_n = (a_n,3)$ (and so $U_n \not\subset E$) to get the same result.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the easist way to define four sequences $a_n, b_n, c_n, d_n$ such that $a_n$ increases to $\sqrt2$, $b_n$ decreases to $\sqrt2$, $c_n$ increases to $\sqrt3$ and $d_n$ decreases to $\sqrt3$? Then one should be able to work with all cases at once: Neither can there be be any finite number of covers inside of $E$, nor outside of $E$, nor inside and outside of $E$. (it's hard to explain without visualisation)

Comment: Yes that would work, but as my comment above, we only need one counterexample to prove non-compactness.

Comment: Are you sure on this one? Intuitively, I wouldn't say so. Refering to your first answer, one could ask what would happen if we would also consider covers that lie outside of E, or covers that "cross" $\Bbb Q$ and $E$, right? Why shouldn't there be a finite cover that "combines" elements from both $\Bbb Q$ and $E$? Your answer is only examining the case where the cover is made up of subspaces that are part of $E$, isn't it?

Comment: Of course some covers may work (but not in this case I don't think) but the definition of compactness states a finite cover must exist for EVERY given open cover. So, to prove the converse (non-compact) one must only demonstrate one cover with no subcover.

Comment: Ah, I guess I didn't comprehend the step where you put $\cup U_n = (\sqrt2, \sqrt3)$, but this is actually the step that allows you to assume that this is indeed a cover in the first place, right?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: Well, then everything should be clear, thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a set of the form $(a,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}$; it's useful to consider $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subspace of its completion $\mathbb{R}$), because this tells us that $(c,d)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$, for any choice of $c,d\in\bar{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$.

Suppose now $a$ is irrational. Then consider a decreasing sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$.

Then the sets
$$
(a_n,b)\cap\mathbb{Q}
$$
provide an open cover of $(a,b)$ with no finite subcover.